# Find all objects that contain a property with a given key using JPath

Tags: jpath

Is it possible to (and if so how do I) recursively get a list of all objects within an object that contains a property with a given key or a given key in a set of keys using JPath?

**Example**

For this object searching for the `type` property:

```
[
  {
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    children: 
    [
      {
        type: 'text'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Some object without a type'
  }
]
```

I would get:

```
[
  {
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    type: 'folder'
    children:
    [
      {
        type: 'text'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'text'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You can use this query syntax:

`$..[?(@.type)]`

To explain it:

1. `$` is the root node selector
2. `..` is the recursive query syntax
3. `[...]` Subscript operator
4. `?(...)` is the expression/ filter syntax
5. `@.type` checks for the existence of the type property on the current node being evaluated

as outlined on

https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/